Understanding received data in flutter_blue_plus
I'm a newbie in Flutter and am trying to build an application that scans for BLE devices and does further processing, I'm able to scan / connect / do some stuff but I want to understand the device data being sent back to me like say -
ScanResult{device: BluetoothDevice{remoteId: E8:2B:B8:53:BF:C9, platformName: Digital_Lock, services: null}, 
advertisementData: AdvertisementData{advName: , txPowerLevel: null, appearance: null, connectable: true, 
manufacturerData: {89: [39, 66, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 86, 100, 200, 20, 235, 119, 180, 100, 76, 229, 242, 217, 251, 227, 123, 138]}, 
serviceData: {}, 
serviceUuids: []}, 
rssi: -93, 
timeStamp: 2024-10-15 10:01:31.698689}

To be more specific, the manufacturerData ,  like what are these values supposed to mean, are they encoded in utf8? I'm guessing there might be some kind of device ID / serial number in it?
Help is appreciated.

89 is Nordic Semiconductor. Ask them how the data format is defined. Manufacturer data is, well, manufacturer specific.

Sounds like an answer, Emil!
